# Node.js (node-webkit) error using http.get for rss feed, HPE_INVALID_CONSTANT

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

I'm working on an RSS aggregator via node-webkit, and I've stumbled upon an issue where a seemingly random volume of my requests (code below) will fail with any of the following errors: HPE_INVALID_CONSTANT, ETIMEDOUT, EAGAIN, and HPE_INVALID_HEADER_TOKEN. I've sorted those in regularity of occurrence.

I made a test.html file with as much relevance as possible. Just plug in a large volume of web page urls into `httpList` and it will work. though, be careful what URLs you use, you wouldn't want to crash someones server! A list of around 56 seems to work for causing the errors.

As an aside, this is really hard to reproduce, meaning its gotta be something I can change on my end. Sometimes the same URL will fail, while on the next pass it will work. Also I have had URLs that have failed, that were indeed accessible (I opened them up in chrome no problem).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTTP Get test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
        var httpList = [];
        var fromUrl = function(stringUrl) {
            var http = require('http');
            var url = require("url");
            var urlData = url.parse(stringUrl);
            var parser = window.document.createElement('a');
            parser.href = stringUrl;
            var options = {
                host: urlData.host,
                path: urlData.path + urlData.search + urlData.hash
            };

            var httpResponse = function(response) {
                response.setEncoding('utf8');
                request.setSocketKeepAlive(true);
                var str = '';

                response.on('data', function(chunk) {
                    str += chunk;
                });

                response.on('end', function() {
                    request.setSocketKeepAlive(false);
                    console.log("url",stringUrl,"was successfully parsed");
                });
            }

            var request = http.request(options, httpResponse)
            request.on('error', function(e) {
                if (e.code === "ENOTFOUND") {
                    console.error("The feed", stringUrl, "could not be fetched.")
                } else {
                    console.log(e, e.message, stringUrl);
                }
            });
            request.end();
        };
        for(var i=0;i<httpList.length;i++) {
            fromUrl(httpList[i]);
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

See this [node issue](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/4863). BTW is not "solved".